# I'm having trouble hooking up a new printer. It says it is not communicating

Tags: usb, printing, printer

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8z8CkVo.jpg]

The above image shows the error I am getting. This printer worked fine previously for a short time, however now whenever I attempt to print from a web page the error box displays. I have printed a test page from the printers menu, and that works fine. I have already attempted to resolve the issue multiple times by following the on-screen suggestions, but to no avail. Can anyone help me resolve my issue? This is a serious problem with my productivity as my printer is an essential part of working.

Oddly enough, I just noticed that my speakers are not working as well.  The light is on, but no sound is coming out. Could these issues be related?

Comment: tried switching the cable, and/or turning off and unplugging in the printer for a while then turning it on again?

Comment: Yes, I've switched the cable a few times.  I also turned off the printer as well as the computer, neither helped unfortunately.

Comment: Is the printer under warranty? Its possible its, well, broken

Comment: I don't think it is, it's a fairly old model.  I don't think it's broken because it printed a test page just fine.  It only ceased to work this morning.

Comment: Tried printing a word document or a web page using another browser?

Comment: Printing using a web browser gives me that error, as does printing from MSPAINT or WINWORD applications.

Comment: Try a diagnostic boot implemented through the msconfig utility. Clear the non essentials, especially your AV. Also ensure you're using the latest printer driver obtained through the manufacturers website.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how

Answer (score 1):

First, the easiest thing -- make sure that the print spooler is running:  Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services, and verify that the print Spooler service shows as "Started".  You can also start it from a command prompt with "NET START SPOOLER".

Assuming that the service is running, the cable is good & the printer is working, the easiest way to resolve this is actually to completely remove the printer by deleting the device in Windows as well as unplugging it, then restart your system, start Windows, and then plug the printer in to re-install it.

If your speakers are also USB-connected, make sure that they (and the printer) are plugged directly into the computer, not into a hub.  Even better, unplug all USB devices except the printer and, of course, keyboard & mouse if needed.

If the remove/re-install process fails, use Control Panel, System, Device Manager and make sure that you do not have any items showing with a yellow exclamation point (esp. "HID"-anything, which are the USB devices.)  Sometimes there is an issue with a component like the "USB Root Hub".  In Device Manager, you may have to click on View > Show Hidden Devices, to see what is not working.

It would help to know what version of Windows you are running, and whether the data light or display on the printer shows it receiving any data at all.